# SSIS Conditional Split Multiple True Paths

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a dataflow inside a dtsx package that processes all of the data that I need to process. At the end, I need to perform some clean up tasks. For example, assume the following stucture:

[image: What I'd like to do]

If a record is true for all 3 cases then I want to run all three OLE DB Commands. If the record is true for only case 1 then it should only run case 1.

I could do this with a multicast and 3 seperate conditional splits (as per below), but I was hoping for a cleaner way. Any ideas?

[image: Possible alternative. Is there a better way?]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using **a multicast and three conditional splits** is the easiest to implement, and is also probably the most easily understood.

**A Script Component set up as a Transformation with three outputs** is probably the next easiest to implement - but it will involve a bunch of setup and some level of coding. The data flow will look relatively pretty:

[image]

For each output, make sure to set the `Synchronous Input ID` to `None` (so that you can control when rows are created); then you'll need to duplicate each of the input columns in each output. The script code itself will look like this:

```cs
public override void IncomingRows_ProcessInputRow(IncomingRowsBuffer Row)
{
    if (Case1Logic(Row))
    {
        Case1OutputBuffer.AddRow();
        Case1OutputBuffer.ProductId = Row.ProductID;
        Case1OutputBuffer.Name = Row.Name;
        // etc. for all columns
    }
    if (Case2Logic(Row))
    {
        Case2OutputBuffer.AddRow();
        Case2OutputBuffer.ProductId = Row.ProductID;
        Case2OutputBuffer.Name = Row.Name;
        // etc. for all columns
    }
    if (Case3Logic(Row))
    {
        Case3OutputBuffer.AddRow();
        Case3OutputBuffer.ProductId = Row.ProductID;
        Case3OutputBuffer.Name = Row.Name;
        // etc. for all columns
    }
}

private bool Case1Logic(IncomingRowsBuffer Row)
{
    // Whatever the Case 1 logic involves
}
private bool Case2Logic(IncomingRowsBuffer Row)
{
    // Whatever the Case 2 logic involves
}
private bool Case3Logic(IncomingRowsBuffer Row)
{
    // Whatever the Case 3 logic involves
}
```

Have fun keeping this up to date when people decide they want to change the columns!

If that's not hairy enough for you, you could write your own **custom transformation**. The gory details on how to do that are in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135931.aspx); suffice it to say that there will be a **lot** more code involved. You'll also learn more than you maybe ever wanted to about how SSIS handles buffer management, which may in turn explain why the out-of-the-box Conditional Split doesn't let you send the same row to more than one output.

Finally, if you want a truly ugly-looking solution that will also be a maintenance nightmare, try building a **Conditional Split with one output for each combination of cases**. Put a Union All tranformation in front of each of your OLE destinations. Direct the `Cases 1, 2 and 3` output to a three-way Multicast, with one multicast output going to each of the three Union All transformations. The `Cases 1 and 2`, `Cases 2 and 3` and `Cases 1 and 3` outputs of the Conditional Split would each go to two-way Multicast transformations (which would in turn feed the appropriate Union All), while the `Case 1`, `Case 2` and `Case 3` outputs would go directly to the appropriate Union All. It would look something like this:

[image]

**In summary**, I think your original idea is the simplest and probably best.

Comment: Wow. thanks for all the effort and details. I think I will stick with my original.

Comment: I think that's the best choice, unless you really want to get into nitty-gritty programming. (Which, sometimes, some of us really like to do ...)  Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how comfortable you are with C# or VB, you could write your own transform that is essentially the multicast and conditional split in one. Add a script component onto the data flow and it'll ask you whether it's a source, transform, or destination. Choose transform, add your input and three outputs and go from there. Good luck!

Comment: I guess that would work. Seems like a bit of effort just to keep it neat. I was hoping for something built in...